# How to reduce height of navbar in bootstrap v4.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Trying to reduce the height of the navbar in bootstrap v4.1 without any luck. I'd like the height to be set at 24px;

Kind regards,
Richard.

Comment: can you post sample code?

Answer (score 1):

Since bootstrap is built on css you can cascade styles. Adding

```
.navbar {
    height: 24px;
}
```

after referencing bootstrap css will cascade height for navbar.

that is,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
<style>
  .navbar {
        height: 24px;
    }
</style>
```

if you are using link tag. If you are using node imports, add another css file containing
overrides and import after.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './path/override.css'
```

You can force by adding !important also. But bootstrap is a responsive framework and modifying or forcing some elements for specific styles may sometimes break its functionality.